# Cypress. Cómo hacer check en un grupo de inputs y saltarse aquellos que ya tengan check

Tags: javascript, test, testing

Estoy empezando ha implementar cypress en un proyecto de vue. Tengo un grupo de inputs `(type="checkbox")` los cuales he de hacer check, el problema es que algunos ya tiene el check dado y tengo que saltarlos, no obstante he probado ya varias opciones con cypress y no consigo hacer lo que quiero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Añado una imagen para mostrar el esquema que tiene cada input a seleccionar, porque los que están seleccionados por defecto, no tienen un checked ni nada(están generados de manera dinámica en vue)

Answer (score 1):

Combinando cypress y jquery se puede llegar a una solución:

```
it('Check checkboxes', () => {
    cy.get('.form-checkbox [type="checkbox"]')
        .each(($elem) => {
            if (!$elem.prop('checked') && !$elem.prop('disabled')) {
                cy.wrap($elem).check();
            }
        })
});
```

});

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a probar.

Comment: muchas gracias. He hecho unas pequeñas modificaciones, no obstante, en esencia, tú respuesta es perfecta. Muchas gracias. Había usado jQuery muy poco y estaba cometiendo algunos errores. A element no le estaba anteponiedo.

Comment: Que bien que haya funcionado!

Answer (score 0):

He seguido el código que ha pasado @LeonardoMartinez, así que todo el crédito es para él. Yo sólo he hecho unas modificaciones para adaptarlo a lo que necesitaba.

```js
cy.get('[data-cy=check-employee-filters] > input').each(($element)=> {
  if(!$element.prop('checked')) {
     cy.wrap($element).check();
   }
})
```